# function intervals of increase and decrease on trig function

Tags: education

Im having a hard time finding the intervals where the function: `f[x_] := x^2 - 4x + 7 Cos[x]` is increasing and decreasing using mathematica. I tried using `FindRoot` but it's not too accurate because the curve has inflection points beyond just the zeroes.[image]

I did this so far, which is wrong. I'm trying to find where it increases and decreases on the interval $[-4,4]$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just added an image of what i did so far

Comment: If all that's provided is an image of code, then people cannot copy/paste the code and must rewrite from scratch if they wish to provide assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking `h[x_] := x^2 - 4x + 7 Cos[x]`, you can find all roots of `h'` in the interval $[-4,4]$ with

```
Solve[h'[x] == 0 && -4 <= x <= 4, x]
```

However, you can get the intervals where `h` is increasing and decreasing directly as inequalities with `Reduce`:

```
increasing = Reduce[h'[x] > 0 && -4 <= x <= 4, x]
decreasing = Reduce[h'[x] < 0 && -4 <= x <= 4, x]
```

You can also generalize to outside of the interval $[-4,4]$:

```
allincreasing = Reduce[h'[x] > 0, x]
alldecreasing = Reduce[h'[x] < 0, x]
```

If you'd like the numeric forms of the roots, simply apply `N`, e.g. `N @ increasing`.

Comment: Thank you so so much!

Comment: Would you know how to find the intervals of concavity of the same function?

Comment: Same thing, just use `h''` instead of `h'`—"concavity" is exactly whether the *derivative* is increasing or decreasing, so you just repeat the procedure with the derivative of the derivative!